# Creating a little Batch file to manage files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

First, sorry if my english isn't good, I'm from Spain.

I have a bunch of files (thousands), spreaded among a bunch of folders (dozens) inside a folder called INSTANCE. There are only 2 filetypes (*.new, *.old). Not in every folder are the two of them. I need to move each *.new file inside a new folder for each 100 of them. And if any *.old file exists move all of them to a separate folder. I've tried doing it by hand, but after a bunch of hours I realize this is a major task, so I'm wondering if it's possible to do it with a batch file, either all folders at once or doing it in every folder inside the INSTANCE folder.

As maybe it sounds confusing, I show first an example as it is now and a second example of how it has to be (instead of 100s I show groups of 3s).

**Before:**

```
D:\[2016]\[01 JANUARY]\INSTANCE
│
├───aaa
│       01.new
│       02.new
│       03.new
│       04.new
│       05.new
│       13.old
│       14.old
│
├───bbb
│       01.new
│       02.new
│       03.new
│       04.new
│       05.new
│       06.new
│       07.new
│       08.new
│       13.old
│       14.old
│       15.old
│
├───ccc
│       01.new
│       02.new
│       03.new
│       04.new
│       05.new
│
└───ddd
        01.new
        02.new
        03.new
        04.new
        05.new
        06.new
        07.new
        08.new
        09.new
        11.old
```

**After:**

```
D:\[2016]\[01 JANUARY]\INSTANCE
│
├───aaa
│   ├───01
│   │       01.new
│   │       02.new
│   │       03.new
│   │
│   ├───02
│   │       04.new
│   │       05.new
│   │
│   └───zz
│           13.old
│           14.old
│
├───bbb
│   ├───01
│   │       01.new
│   │       02.new
│   │       03.new
│   │
│   ├───02
│   │       04.new
│   │       05.new
│   │       06.new
│   │
│   ├───03
│   │       07.new
│   │       08.new
│   │
│   └───zz
│           13.old
│           14.old
│           15.old
│
├───ccc
│   ├───01
│   │       01.new
│   │       02.new
│   │       03.new
│   │
│   └───02
│           04.new
│           05.new
│
└───ddd
    ├───01
    │       01.new
    │       02.new
    │       03.new
    │
    ├───02
    │       04.new
    │       05.new
    │       06.new
    │
    ├───03
    │       07.new
    │       08.new
    │       09.new
    │
    └───zz
            11.old
```

**Summarizing:**

```
Look inside INSTANCE

  for every folder inside

    if any *.old file exists create a folder called ZZ and move there all of them

  Then

    create folder 01 and move 100 of the *.new files
    create folder 02 and move the next 100
    create folder 03 and move the next 100
    ...

Until all the files have been moved
```

Before searching how to do it, because I'm not a programmer, I want to know if it's possible and it is worth it for me the learning curve because it's a one time thing. I read there are some commands that can help with some of the tasks (MD, IF EXIST, MOVE, etc...) but not if I can do it all in a single batch file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Now you can do your searching. Good luck.

Comment: Is the cronology of the .new files important ? Or its just take 100 of .new files and copy it. Are your files really named 01,02,03,04 ?

Comment: @Ken White Thanks. I'm now trying to understand how to group the files by 100 in a loop

Comment: @SachaDee The order isn't important because the content varies. Is only for having them in a more manageable manner. The new ones are stored in a different way.

Here is an actual list of files: `--CWyGnu.new, --MP.new, 0OUhSGhG.new, 1oDCoUsA.new, 35RUmD-C.new, 4wTTSGp-.new, 7NqaO.new, 9tj7rJos.new, BCLrlx4BD.new, BIJ0-DcXo.new, CGQR7.new, HSic.new, NKwRs.new, QXv8SGgJ.new, Tyt6.new, Vykm.new, Yl_myGjR.new, bIDJX.new, d40pva7v.new, eranCLx0Qic1x.new, eranVZa3cic9N.new, ftGQPaxe.new, hrrdSGuz.new, kSum.new, rvGUmDyv.new, vijJV.new, z_LgR4N_.new, zyafSGhD.new, zyhc.new`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o\instance"
SET /a filesperdir=3
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

REM For each directory found in "sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "dirname=%%a"
 REM initialise subdirectory counter and file counter
 SET /a subcount=0
 SET /a filecount=filesperdir
 REM scan for files "*.new"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%c IN (
  'dir /b /a-d ".\%%a\*.new" 2^>nul'
  ) DO (
   REM name of file and move
   SET "filename=%%c"
   CALL :movenew
 )
 REM scan for files "*.old"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%c IN (
  'dir /b /a-d ".\%%a\*.old" 2^>nul'
  ) DO (
   rem move to "zz"
   MD ".\%%a\zz" >NUL 2>NUL
   ECHO(MOVE ".\%%a\%%c" ".\%%a\zz\"
 )
)

popd

GOTO :EOF

:movenew
REM one more file...
SET /a filecount +=1
REM filled this subdirectory?
if %filecount% gtr %filesperdir% SET /a subcount+=1&SET /a filecount=1
SET /a subnum=1000+subcount
REM try to make subdirectory
MD ".\%dirname%\%subnum:~-2%" >nul 2>nul
ECHO(MOVE ".\%dirname%\%filename%" ".\%dirname%\%subnum:~-2%\"
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

I've commented in-line about how the job is done. Note that you need to use `rem` not `::` (often used as a quicker-to-type alternative) because this trick (`::` in place of `REM`) does not work within acode-block (parenthesised series of statements)

Rough outline : for reac subdirectory found, set the subdir count to 0 and filecount to max. Process the subdir first for `.new` files and then `.old`. For the `old` files, the processing is simple; just move them to a subdirectory `zz`. For the `new` files, run the subroutine `movenew`.

`:movenew` adds 1 to the count-of-files-moved and if the result is greater than the number allowed, increment the subdirectory count and reset the filecount.

then use `subnum` to calculate the subdirectory name (last 2 characters of the string) - adding `1000` to `subcount` ensures that `subnum` is always 4-digits.
Then create the directory and move the file.

Note that the `md` willl create an error message if the directory already exists. The `2>nul` suppresses this error message. The `2^>nul` in the `dir` commands serves a similar purpose for directories that contain none of the target filetype. The caret `^` tells the processor that the `>` is part of the command being executed, not of the `for` itself.

Comment: WOW! I'm surprise that it was less lines than I tought but more complicated to understand.  Altough I've found this: the `filesperdir` value I need is 100. Said that, with a value of 3 the subdirectory names for the *.new files increase from 01 up to 99 every 3 files and then begins again in 01. If I understood well, you told the names begins from 1000 up? Anyway, I don't think I have moren than 10000 files per dir (100*99) so changing the `filesperdir` value to 100 doesn't affect the result.

Comment: You can set `filesperdir` to any value you want. Since your destination directories are named `01`..`99` then if there are more than 99*filesperdir files to be moved, the next directoryname is (1000+100)=1100 (last 2 chars=`00`) and the one after that is (1000+101)=1101 (last 2 chars=`01`) and so on. If you want to generate 3-digit directory names, use `%subnum:~-3%` in place of `%subnum:~-2%` OR leave as-is and set `filesperdir` so that no more than 99 directories are created.

Comment: I've fixed the generation of the `zz` directory. `   MD ".\%%a\zz" >NUL 2>NUL` in place of `   MD ".\zz" >NUL 2>NUL`

Comment: Like I said it works perfect with this changes. The only thing I can say in favour of the @Aacini solution is that his is faster if the directory contains a huge number of files, at least in this computer. But once I understand the most part of the code, I think i am far away from doing this by myself from scratch. Thanks guys, you saved me hours of work and life.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Look inside INSTANCE
cd /D "D:\[2016]\[01 JANUARY]\INSTANCE"

rem for every folder...
for /D %%f in (*) do (
   rem ... inside
   cd "%%f"

   rem if any *.old file exists...
   if exist *.old (
      rem ... create a folder called ZZ...
      md ZZ
      rem ... and move there all of them
      move *.old ZZ
   )

   rem Then, create folders with two-digits and move 100 *.new files to each one
   set /A twoDigits=100, files=-1
   for %%a in (*.new) do (
      set /A files+=1, filesMOD100=files%%100
      rem Every 100 files, when the remainder of files/100 is zero...
      if !filesMOD100! equ 0 (
         rem ... create a new two-digits folder
         set /A twoDigits+=1
         md !twoDigits:~-2!
      )
      move "%%a" !twoDigits:~-2!
   )

   rem Go back to original folder -INSTANCE-
   cd ..

)
```

Comment: Same as @Magoo, WOW! This works at the first try and it's more like I had in mind, altough it has some parts that I don't understant but I will try to in case I need them in the future (like `filesMOD100`) Thanks for share your knowledge and teach other people.

Comment: The _modulo operation_ (given by the `%` operator in `set /A` command) is the remainder of the integer division. For example, "5 mod 2" is 1 and "9 mod 3" is 0; see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). ¡Saludos desde México!

Comment: It would be helpful to remember all the math lessons. Gracias por todo.